# how to dynamicly calculate angular class var

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
export class example {
  @Input() a;
  @Input() b;
  c；
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

a and b will change dynamiclly.I want c be like this:c=a+b;how can i do that like react's state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a getter

```
@Component({ /* ...  */})
export class SomeComponent {
   @Input() numberA: number;
   @Input() numberB: number;

   constructor() { }

   get numberC() {
       return this.numberA + this.numberB;
   }
}
```

Then you can bind to it using `{{ numberC }}`. Everytime `numberC` is accessed it will compute the value from the current state of `numberA` and `numberB`

I changed the names of the properties for more clarity, you can read more on `Typescript getters and setters [here](http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/javascript-getters-setters-typescript-accessor-tutorial/)